# Using RequireJS or not

Tags: javascript, performance, requirejs

What are the advantages of using requireJS if all the script files are merged into one in production?

Im working on a multiple page project.

Comment: If all your script files are merged into one, RequireJS won't bring you much (unless, of course, you are using it to [combine](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) your scripts in the first place).

Comment: We don't use requireJS itself but a similar library. While we also merge the scripts together in he final productive environment, we have the scripts separated while development to make debugging easier. For production the requireJS syntax is striped out and merging is done.

Comment: I also found requirejs hard to use with other libraries and vice-versa. That is why I created a library which is much easier to use and is tested with angular. There is a demo application at the bottom: gngeorgiev.github.io/Modulerr.js You can also combine all scripts into one without the dependency to Modulerr.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only merge the files for staging and production. In development you keep them separate.

This lets you manage your JavaScript by dividing it into discrete units. This makes it easier to test, easier to reuse and easier to find the piece of code you need to change.

Comment: How do I strip requireJS syntax for production then ?

Comment: You don't strip it. There's no need.

Comment: @Newcoma Modernizr make use of the r.js build options to strip require/define from their build. Check it here - https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L144

Comment: Thanks I will look into that. Already using the r.js